# Downloading a file with php fails

Tags: php

The file that I have is:

```
$file_path='CSVs/data'.time().'TaskID_'.$this->task_id.'.csv';
```

Then I attach it to this function.

```
$save_to="Y:\SEO\Avi\BackLinks";
$this->download_remote_file(
    "http://212.13.98.158/backlinks/".$file_path, $save_to);

function download_remote_file($file_url, $save_to)
{
    $content = file_get_contents($file_url);
    file_put_contents($save_to, $content);
}
```

That file should retrieve the files contents and copy it to the directory.

The errors that I get are to do with 404 and that the folder doesnt exist. But I do know for a fact, that the folder exists..and I am quite sure that the links is the right link that points to the resource

**UPDATE:** 
mADE THE CHANGES..this simple example..throws me 403 forbidden. saying that the file or directory doesnt exist.

```
    $save_to="Y:\SEO\Avi\BackLinks\data1335692353TaskID_122.csv";
      $this->download_remote_file("http://212.199.198.158/backlinks/CSVs/data1335692353TaskID_122.csv", $save_to);
```

Comment: Where is the full path name in `$save_to`? Does it have the filename and extention?

Comment: How are you so sure the `$file_path` exists? Did you echo it just before the `file_get_contents`, and then check it? You _are_ doing a `time()` call, are you sure you have a file for every second? An is the `taks_id` correct?

Comment: http://212.13.98.15/backlinks/data1335692201TaskID_122.csv ..this one does exist... I can reach it

Comment: I can't reach 212.13.98.15/backlinks/data1335692201TaskID_122.csv. I get a connection error. But that may be a permissions setting on the folder.

Comment: Okay, The file path was fixed... Now the problem is with the directory..file put content..It does exist..but..why is it written that it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your file_path: `212.13.98.15/backlinks/data1335692201TaskID_122.csv`.
It is not the path in the post: `$file_path='CSVs/data'.time().'TaskID_'.$this->task_id.'.csv'`;
Remove the **CSVs/**

And what about the filename and its extention? You need them to tell under which name to write a file.

Your `$save_to` has to be a kind of `$save_to="Y:\SEO\Avi\BackLinks\abc.cvs";`

**UPDATE** - Try each operation separately. First, echo the get_file_contents, or a few lines of it. Then try to put a simple "hello.txt" or whatever on your savepath.

If then you'll recieve same error - check the permissions.

Comment: I fixed it..It works..now I get 403 ..I think I have a permission issue of writting the file

Comment: Are you sure you have the permissions to write?

Comment: I get this..You don't have permission to access /backlinks/CSVs/data1336462992TaskID_330.csv on this server. on this server

Comment: This is what I get without using put contents..only after get contents

Comment: Cool. That's the real problem that should be solved =) I guess, you need to change the permissions on the holding server, if you have the access.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the remote file doesn't exists. 
You use `time()` to build the file path: this function returns a different value every second, so you can print out correctly the path of an existing file, but a second later the path changes and you can't download it.

Comment: that is not the right answer. I use time only once...and then store it in a string.. I dont think it stores the function inside in the string

Comment: No, it doesn't, but you wrote in your post a dynamical `$file_path`

Comment: Okay, The file path was fixed... Now the problem is with the directory..file put content..It does exist..but..why is it written that it doesnt

Comment: is it permission problem ?!? anyway I can fix that? 403 forbidden